# How can I pass a value from my react component to my back-end (express)

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I'm trying to build a dashboard for my website with react/d3 for learning purpose. I've start building a simple react/d3 app, I'm using express to get the data with the Google Analytics API. I would like to be able to recall my Google Analytics API dynamically with different parameters.

I have no idea how my front-end is supposed to pass a value to my back-end.

so let's say I have the following react component with a list of name:

```
class authorL extends React.Component {
                      constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                      }
                      render() {
                            var props = this.props.name;
                        return (
                  <div>
                                <ul>
                  { props.map((m, i) =>
                    <li key={i} onClick={() => this.props.getFilteredName(m.name)}>{m.name}</li>
                  )}
                </ul>
                </div>
                        )
                      };
                     }
```

When clicking on one of this name I'm passing the name I'm clicking on with the following action :

```
export function AuthorFilter(name) {
    return {
      type: 'SET_NAME',
      name,
        };
      }
```

so let's say my reducers and all are ok. how do I pass this name as a value into my express file, which right now, looks like this :

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.use('/', express.static('src'));

var ga = require('./src/apicall/gadata');

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.set('views', './src/views');      
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use('/gadata', ga.queryData);
```

if needed I can post my GA API call script.

Please I'm a beginner, if my question is unclear help me to improves it.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried declaring an Express route, and then issuing an AJAX request to it from the front-end?

Comment: Nop. Like I said I have no idea on how I should do this. about what you said, do you have an example somewhere ? What should be the basics element of this express route ? Of this AJAX request ? Thanks.